# /usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-11.0.16.0.8-1.amzn2.0.1.x86_64 doesn’t look like a JDK directory

Tags: java, jenkins, amazon-ec2, java-11

I am trying to install java 11 on an amazon ec2 instance Linux , I followed the below steps:

====OS details=====

```
[root@ip-172-31-44-83 java-11-openjdk-11.0.16.0.8-1.amzn2.0.1.x86_64]# cat /etc/os-release
NAME="Amazon Linux"
VERSION="2"
ID="amzn"
ID_LIKE="centos rhel fedora"
VERSION_ID="2"
PRETTY_NAME="Amazon Linux 2"
ANSI_COLOR="0;33"
CPE_NAME="cpe:2.3:o:amazon:amazon_linux:2"
HOME_URL="https://amazonlinux.com/"
```

```
===Install Java=====
sudo amazon-linux-extras
sudo amazon-linux-extras install java-openjdk11 -y
java --version
sudo su -
echo "export JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-11.0.16.0.8-1.amzn2.0.1.x86_64" >> .bash_profile
echo "export PATH=$PATH:/usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-11.0.16.0.8-1.amzn2.0.1.x86_64/bin" >> .bash_profile 
source ~/.bash_profile
echo $JAVA_HOME
java --version
```

installation result: java is successfully installed and even path is also set

```
[root@ip-172-31-44-83 java-11-openjdk-11.0.16.0.8-1.amzn2.0.1.x86_64]# cat ~/.bash_profile
# .bash_profile

# Get the aliases and functions
if [ -f ~/.bashrc ]; then
        . ~/.bashrc
fi

# User-specific environment and startup programs

PATH=$PATH:$HOME/bin

export PATH
export JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-11.0.16.0.8-1.amzn2.0.1.x86_64
export PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/root/bin:/usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-11.0.16.0.8-1.amzn2.0.1.x86_64/bin
[root@ip-172-31-44-83 java-11-openjdk-11.0.16.0.8-1.amzn2.0.1.x86_64]#
[root@ip-172-31-44-83 java-11-openjdk-11.0.16.0.8-1.amzn2.0.1.x86_64]#
[root@ip-172-31-44-83 java-11-openjdk-11.0.16.0.8-1.amzn2.0.1.x86_64]# echo $JAVA_HOME
/usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-11.0.16.0.8-1.amzn2.0.1.x86_64
[root@ip-172-31-44-83 java-11-openjdk-11.0.16.0.8-1.amzn2.0.1.x86_64]# rpm -qa | grep jdk
java-11-openjdk-11.0.16.0.8-1.amzn2.0.1.x86_64
copy-jdk-configs-3.3-10.amzn2.noarch
java-11-openjdk-headless-11.0.16.0.8-1.amzn2.0.1.x86_64
[root@ip-172-31-44-83 java-11-openjdk-11.0.16.0.8-1.amzn2.0.1.x86_64]#
```

When I am adding a java path in Jenkins global tool Configuration getting the below error
"/usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-11.0.16.0.8-1.amzn2.0.1.x86_64 doesn’t look like a JDK directory
"

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Look like the location you are specifying doesn't have `javac`.
to make sure try to check if `javac` exist or not by running:
`ls /usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-11.0.16.0.8-1.amzn2.0.1.x86_64/bin/javac`

if it does not exist then try to download fresh JDK and set JAVA_HOME point to there.

Answer (score 0):

Error Message:

- /usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-11.0.18.0.10-1.amzn2.0.1.x86_64 doesn’t look like a JDK directory

Likely Cause:

- you probably didn't install the java devel package that will generate the javac version needed for jenkins to accept the provided path as a recognisable one.

Solution:

- run: yum reinstall java-11-openjdk-devel
- to confirm installation, run: rpm -q1 java-11-openjdk-devel | grep bin/javac
- restart jenkins by running: systemctl restart jenkins